# How do I simulate a multi page site using jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

The site I am working on is a single page site but I want to simulate a multipage site using css/jQuery to hide/reveal the different sections of the site when the correct link is clicked in the nav.

[Here is the code I am currently working with on JSFiddle.](https://jsfiddle.net/6bu8hdL9/4/)

HTML

```
<header id="top">
 <nav>
  <ul>
   <li> 
    <a href="#about">About</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#skills">Skills</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#projects">Projects</a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a href="#contact">Contact</a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </nav>
</header>

<main role="main" id="main">
 <section id="about">
 </section>
 <section id="skills">
 </section>
 <section id="projects">
 </section>
 <section id="contact">
 </section>
</main>
```

CSS

```
.active {
  background: $lightest-blue;
  color: $blue;
}

.hide-section {
  display: none;
}

section {
  height: 1em;
  background: blue;
}
```

JavaScript

```
// Create Variables pointing to all Nav links and the About section link.
var siteNav = $("#top li").children();
var aboutLink = siteNav[0];

// Create Variables poingting to all Sections and the About section.
var siteSections = $("#main").children();
var aboutSection = siteSections[0];

// Hide all major sections by adding CSS class.
siteSections.addClass("hide-section");

// Upon document being ready, make user "arrive" at the About section by removing the hide class on it.
// Add active class to About section link.
$(function() {
  $(aboutLink).addClass("active");
  $(aboutSection).removeClass("hide-section");
});

// 1. Capture click on Nav anchor.
$("#top a").click(function() {
  // 1.1 Remove active class from all links.
  siteNav.removeClass("active");
  // 1.2 Add active class to clicked link.
  $(this).addClass("active");
  // 1.3 Identify proper section.
  var hrefLink = $(this).attr("href");
  // 1.4 Hide all other sections.
  siteSections.addClass("hide-section");
  // 1.5 Reveal proper section.

});
```

Comment: What are you having problems with?

Comment: It seems to me that you are looking for something like [fullPage.js](http://alvarotrigo.com/fullPage/)

Comment: @Alvaro That is an amazing plugin. Exactly what I was looking for! Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Right hold up, you're trying to reinvent the wheel here! :)

Have a look at the Jquery tabs library:

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/

Just copy the code into your site, 
remove the style sheet link and away you go! :D

Answer (score 0):

Use this javascript to toggle between screens. I added some css so you can see the different sections come and go.

```
$("#top a").click(function() {
 // 1.1 Remove active class from all links.
 siteNav.removeClass("active");
 // 1.2 Add active class to clicked link.
 $(this).addClass("active");
 // 1.3 Identify proper section.
 var hrefLink = $(this).attr("href");
 // 1.4 Hide all other sections.
 $('#'+siteSections[0].id).hide();
 $('#'+siteSections[1].id).hide();
 $('#'+siteSections[2].id).hide();
 $('#'+siteSections[3].id).hide(); 
 // 1.5 Reveal proper section.
 $(hrefLink).show();
});
```

and some css

```
section{
background:red;
}
#about{
 background-color:blue;  
}
#skills{
 background-color:yellow;  
}
```